# HaarTraining with OpenCV error

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv

I have about 15000 cropped images with the object of interest (positive samples) and 7000 negative images (non object of interest). The cropped images have a resolution of 48x96 and are placed in a folder. The .txt file containing the positive samples looks something like this : picture1.pgm 1 0 0 48 96 meaning that there is 1 positive sample in picture 1 from (0,0) to (48, 96). Likewise I have a .txt file for negative images.

The command for training is the following: 
`c:\libraries\OpenCV2.4.1\opencv\built\bin\Debug>opencv_haartrainingd.exe -data d
ata/cascade -vec data/positives.vec -bg c:/users/gheorghi/desktop/daimler/pedest
rian_stereo_extracted/nonpedestrian/nonpedestrian/c0/negatives.txt -npos 15660 -
nneg 7129 -nstage 14 -mem 1000 -mode ALL -w 18 -h 36 -nonsym`

But at some point I always get this error :

```
    Parent node: 0

*** 1 cluster ***
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in unknown function, file C:
\libraries\OpenCV2.4.1\opencv\apps\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1858
```

How can I overcome this ??? Any help is appreciated. Many many thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. *** 1 cluster ***
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (elements_read == 1) in unknown function, file C:
\Program Files\opencv2.4.1\apps\haartraining\cvhaartraining.cpp, line 1858 I'm training with 24x24 in 1000 positive samples and 3000 negative samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem can be solved in 2 ways. you can either decrease the amount of positives or increase the amount of negatives. either way it turns out that having a small positive to negative ratio helps.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543283/1201501).
It may be of some help.

The same issue was posted by many others, i used the advice given [here](http://code.opencv.org/issues/1834).